# Clear Citation Style Cache

Tags: front-end, notebooks, citation-management

How can I clear the "Citation Styles Cache" created when you use the EndNote citation management feature for the first time in *Mathematica*.  The [Citation Management tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CitationManagement.html) indicates that such a cache is created, but gives no indication of how to clear it.

Comment: That tutorial states that the Refresh button clears it and then inserts the new stuff from EndNote database. I'm guessing if the database is empty, the cache will remain empty.